# Regular expression for floating point number Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to ask Regular expression

I have a a float number called 0.11,

in this case, the first digit must be Zero

and there can be at most three decimal digits , like 0.1, 0.11, 0.111

In Java, I code like this

```
String phone_regex = "d{1,1}.d{1,3}";
```

But it does not work...

Can someone provide some suggestion for me?

thank you

Comment: what numbers are matching that should not, or are not matching that should match?

Comment: Pedantic note: if there's a fixed number of digits after the decimal point, it's not a floating-point number.  It's a [fixed-point-number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)...

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping your digit character group `\\d`, e.g.,

```
"^0\\.\\d{1,3}$"
```

This matches all strings beginning with a `0`, followed by a `dot` and `1-3` digits.

`^` means beginning of line, `$` means end of line. See also [java.util.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the numbers class (`\d`) and the `.` char.

```
String phone_regex = "\\d\\.\\d{1,3}";
```